# Can code from TF 1.x read a tfrecords file written using TF 2.x?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tfrecord

Can a `tfrecords` file(s) written using one version of TF be read by code written using a different version of TF? In particular can `tfrecords` files written using TF 2 be read by code written using TF1? Or is the serialization format TF version specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tfrecords files use the protobuf format, which is used by both TF1 and TF2.
So yes, you can read tfrecord files from both versions of tensorflow.

Comment: So then as long as you are using a version of protobuf that is similar it should not be a problem? If someone used TF 2.3 and a bleeding edge version of protobuf to write a TF records file, then as long as the person using TF 1.x was able to use a newish version of protobuf all would be well?

Comment: You're right. Note that protobuf is just a serialization format. You can write many different stuff in this format. Both ends need to agree on the schema (this is the .proto file) and the meaning of the fields.